# How to find values of resistor and capacitors with given formula, circuit and plot

Tags: circuits

I have given circuit [image]
And i need to find values of R1,R2 and C1, C2. Value of E is 20 V and I is 2 A. I just need tips how to start this task.

Comment: A circuit simulator seems a likely candidate.

Comment: The graph isn't labelled. Is it voltage on the vertical and time on the horizontal? Why does the graph change at time = 4, is there a switch somewhere that isn't shown? I is 2 A, is that a current source (makes no sense, may not be solvable), or is it the current at time = 4?

Answer (score 1):

From the graph, you can see that final value is 12V. So, R1+R2 = 4. This is equation 1

You have 3 points at X=6, 8, 10 which correspond to t=2, 4, 6 in your equation. So, you can get 3 equations.

Total 4 equations, 4 unknowns i.e., R1, R2, C1, C2. So, you can solve them.